# Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let also, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(2a_n+\sin(a_n)\right)=\frac\pi3+\frac12$ then $a_n\to\frac \pi6$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Let also, $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(2a_n+\sin(a_n)\right)=\dfrac\pi3+\dfrac12$ then $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=\dfrac \pi6$$

If we knew $\lim a_n$ exists then $\lim \sin(a_n)$ also exists by continuity, then I can find this desired limit. Without assuming existence of the limit $\lim a_n$ can we solve it?

Comment: *Hint*. The function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=2x+\sin x$ is a strictly increasing bijection, hence $f^{-1}$ is a well-defined continuous function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hint of Sangchul Lee is perfect. Below is an alternative proof without using the continuity of inverse functions.

It is clear that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, since $\sin a_n$ and $2a_n+\sin a_n$ are both bounded.

Let $L=\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\in\mathbb R, \ell=\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n\in\mathbb R$. There exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ with $a_{n_k}\to L$, then
$$2L+\sin L=\lim_{k\to\infty}(2a_{n_k}+\sin a_{n_k})=\frac\pi3+\frac12.$$
Let $f(x)=2x+\sin x$, then $f$ is strictly increasing and $f\left(\frac\pi6\right)=\frac\pi3+\frac12$, hence $f(L)= \frac\pi3+\frac12$ implies that $L=\frac\pi6$.

Similarly, there exists a subsequence $a_{m_k}$ such that $a_{m_k}\to\ell$, hence
$$f(\ell)=2\ell+\sin \ell=\lim_{k\to\infty}(2a_{m_k}+\sin a_{m_k})=\frac\pi3+\frac12,$$
so we have $\ell=\frac\pi6$, then $L=\ell=\frac\pi6$,  and hence $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\frac\pi6$.

Comment: Awesome! This can be quickly generalized to yield a simple proof of the continuity of the inverse (of a monotonic continuous function between intervals)!

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for your nice comment!

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$ f(x)=2x+\sin(x). $$
Then by Lagrange's MVT, one has
$$ \left|f(a_n)-f(\frac\pi6)\right|=\left|f'(\xi_n)\right|\left|a_n-\frac\pi6\right|=\left|2+\cos(\xi_n)\right|\left|a_n-\frac\pi6\right|\ge\left|a_n-\frac\pi6\right| $$
for some $\xi_n$ between $a_n$ and $\frac\pi6$.
Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n)=f(\frac\pi6)$ simply implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac\pi6$.

Comment: This one is so elegant! +1

Comment: Thank you @ParamanandSingh

Comment: I have fixed a minor typo which I noticed just now.

Comment: Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x)=2x+\sin x,\quad x\in\mathbb R,$$
then $f'(x)=2+\cos x>0,\forall x\in\mathbb R$.
So $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $\mathbb R$.
So $f^{-1}$ exists and also continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $f^{-1}\left(\dfrac\pi3+\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac\pi6$.
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}f^{-1}(f(a_n))
=f^{-1}(\lim_{n\to\infty}f(a_n))
=f^{-1}\left(\dfrac\pi3+\dfrac12\right)=\dfrac\pi6$$

Comment: Use  the idea of  Sangchul Lee.